# How to run xargs utility on all expanded lines of input?

Tags: macos, zsh, wildcards, xargs, du

I have a file with a list of files and directories, containing the wildcard `*`. I am trying to output the size of the entries with `du` and would like a grand total.

If I start with:

```
cat file | xargs du -hs
```

the wildcard `*` is not expanded. To do so, I do:

```
cat file | xargs -I@ sh -c 'du -hs @'
```

But if I try:

```
cat file | xargs -I@ sh -c 'du -hsc @'
```

I get a total for *each* (expanded) entry of the file. If the file looks like:

```
foo*
bar*
```

I will get:

```
1K foo1
1K foo2
2K total
1K bar1
1K bar2
2K total
```

How do I get the grand total of all entries in the file? How do I run `du` only once for all the lines? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | xargs -I@ sh -c 'echo @' | xargs du -hsc
```

Comment: While your answer may be correct, it requires an explanation for future visitors. And perhaps a link to a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If xargs isn't required, this will also produce a grand total with `du`:

```shell
du -hsc ${(f)~"$(<file)"}
```

This assumes that `file` has one glob pattern per line, and uses the `(f)` expansion flag to split the input into lines. Both the pattern and the filenames can contain spaces. The `GLOB_SUBST` expansion (`${~...}`) tells `zsh` to process the wildcards in the input.

If the patterns are just separated by whitespace, the `(f)` flag isn't needed:

```shell
setopt nullglob
du -hsc ${~$(<file)}
```

This sets the `NULL_GLOB` option. That setting will be necessary if any of the glob patterns do not have matching files.